Picture file and href link to SP List in Header - text on next line
I used this code
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "text-align": "center"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "style": {
                "width": "100%",
                "max-width": "100%"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "src": "https://picsum.photos/500/200"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "*Step Up Program Award Guidelines",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-blue",
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/blabitty/shared%20documents/step%20up%20program%20award%20guidelines.png?web=1"
            },
            "style": {
                "font-size": "24px"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I utilized your code which worked great, but I want my image to be at approx 75% vs the 100% due to it looking blurry on my monitor (but fine on laptop). When I do that, the linked text is next to the image instead of below. How can I get the hyperlink to stay below the image when I make the image smaller?

We can try to add a div tag outside the a tag, since the div element occupies one line exclusively.
Please try the following JSON code:
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "block",
    "text-align": "center"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "width": "75%",
        "max-width": "75%"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "xxxxx"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "a",
          "txtContent": "*Step Up Program Award Guidelines",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-blue",
            "target": "_blank",
            "href": "xxxxxx"
          },
          "style": {
            "font-size": "24px"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

